# How to append Iframe in div using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I was trying to append an Iframe embed to a div element using javascript but I'm getting an error when trying to append it using innerHtml. Is there any way to append an Iframe in a div using javascript. My current code is attached below. Thanks in advance.

```js
function addCode() {
  document.getElementById("add_to_me").innerHTML +=
    "<iframe width="
  1263 " height="
  480 " src="
  https: //www.youtube.com/embed/zogtwLQQEfY" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>";
}
```

```html
<div id="add_to_me">
  <h3> Heading</h3>
  <!--embed Iframe here-->
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string contains attributes that are wrapped with double quotes - `"`. Wrap the entire string with single quotes - `'`.

```js
document.getElementById("add_to_me").innerHTML +=
  '<iframe width="1263" height="480" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zogtwLQQEfY" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
```

```html
<div id="add_to_me">
  <h3> Heading</h3>
  <!--embed Iframe here-->
</div>
```

Comment: is there any way to save that appended code to the default HTML permanently @Ori Drori

Comment: You'll need to change the original HTML file to do so. The other option is to change via JS if you can add it to the page.

Comment: By change the original HTML You mean recreating a new file with the updated code in it? If so does this mean there is no way of updating the default code automatically when the addcode function runs?@Ori Drori

Comment: Sorry. I don't understand what you need.